# python crypto high level wrapper

Tags: python, google-app-engine, aes, pycrypto

I'm using PyCrypto (on google app engine) for AES encryption.

PyCrypto gives I guess a raw interface to AES--i need to pad my keys and my inputs to 16 byte multiples.

Is there a higher level library which takes care of this stuff for me?

Comment: Well, it is only two lines of code to pad your keys and inputs...

Comment: And most other tested implementations compiled modules and/or OpenSSL, which will not work with AppEngine.  As an interesting side note and possible starting point, here is a nice readable implementation in pure python: http://brandon.sternefamily.net/posts/2007/06/aes-tutorial-python-implementation/

Comment: i imagine it will be more complicated than that.